# Send parameter to custom validationrule

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

Is it possible to send a parameter to a custom validationrule?

My validationrule:

```
public class CustomTypeSelectedRule : IValidationRule
{
    public ValidationResult Validate(object input)
    {
        // Here I need an extra value from the class calling
        // the validation rule.

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

My property using the validationrule:

```
[ContractValidation(typeof(ValidationRules.CustomTypeSelectedRule))]
public int CustomType
{
    get
    {
        return this.customType;
    }
    set
    {
        this.customType = value;
    }
}
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might help you - 
http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/wpf-custom-validationrule-with-an-additional-parameter/

Comment: Need to do it by code. I found a way around using the Enterprise Library validation framework.